# Have multiple includes in a php file

Tags: php, html, web-deployment

I am trying to call 2 functions that i have in 2 separate .php files. Let's say that function1() is in my_functions1.php and function2() is in my_functions2.php.

lets say i have in the same folder a third file called main.php and i want to include the functions from both my_functions1.php and my_functions2.php.

Something like this

```
<?php
include 'my_functions1.php';
include 'my_functions2.php';

function1();
function2();

?>
```

For some reason i can't have 2 include files. I am kind of new in PHP and it seems that there is nothing on google about this except of putting all the functions in one file.

Comment: Where is the error? Can you show us your both php files?

Comment: I work on projects with *thousands* of include files. You must be doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using include_once. You might be accidentally including the same file multiple times.